# Is it possible to get the grep path output in a variable?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, rhel

I'm having trouble in a script and i want to know if it's possible to store the path of the matching result of a grep ?

I'm on RHEL 7, the script is a check of the rsyslog.conf file which complete or add the correct value to a parameter (CIS rhel7 benchmark, part 4.2.1.3).

Full script so far :

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep "^\$FileCreateMode" /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
then
    read -p "Is $FileCreateMode superior or equal to 0640 ? [y/n]" rep
    if [ $rep == "y" ]
    then
        echo "No action needed"
    else
        read -p "Enter the new $FileCreateMode value (0640 recommanded)" rep2
        sed -i "/^\$FileCreateMode/ $rep2" 
        echo "$FileCreateMode new value is now $rep2"
    fi
else
    echo "$FileCreateMode doesn't exist in rsyslog conf files"
    read -p "What's the path of the file to modify ?(Press [ENTER] for default /etc/rsyslog.conf)" path
    if [ $path -z ] 
    then
        echo "$FileCreateMode 0640" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf
    else
        echo "$FileCreateMode 0640" >> $path
    fi
fi
```

So my problem is on the sed at the 11th line.
Am i able to get the right path if my grep on 3rd line matched into a variable to reuse it on the 11th.

And i'm struggling with the same sed because i want him to replace the value after $FileCreateMode but it keep changing the $FileCreateMode string.

i've tried this syntax too but i still don't get the result i want

```
sed -i -e "s,^\($FileCreateMode[ ]*\).*,\1 0640 ,g" /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can bring, and have a good day :)

Edit :

As requested i'm simplifying here.

I want to grep $FileCreateMode in /etc/rsyslog.conf and /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf and i'm trying to get the destination file (could be rsyslog.conf but it can be testpotato.conf in rsyslog.d) into a variable (like $var) to be able to use the path in my sed on the 11th line like

```
sed -i "/^\$FileCreateMode/ 0640" $var
```

And for the sed problem when i execute this command i would like to have something like

```
old : $FileCreateMode 0777
sed -i "/^\$FileCreateMode/ 0640" $var
new : $FileCreateMode 0640
```

But instead i get

```
old : $FileCreateMode 0777
sed -i "/^\$FileCreateMode/ 0640" $var
new : 0640 ($FileCreateMode is deleted)
```

hope i'm more understable, thanks again and feel free to ask for more details

Comment: This is not a [minimum, viable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you either post such an example or explain in more details what `grep` returns in different cases? As it is I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: I get what you are doing, you want to make sure that $FileCreateMode is at least 0640.  But what are you trying to accomplish after that?  The sed, as it is, looks ok.  If I run your grep, I get `/etc/rsyslog.conf:$FileCreateMode 0640`, so what is *the right path* that you want to reuse?  Explain better your problem, with samples of the problem.

Comment: I edited the post to be more specific, i hope it would be more understandable. Sorry if the first post was a bit sketchy it's the first time i post here.

Comment: Isn't `grep -H` what you are looking for?

Comment: @rkta well i'm using it wrong then i'm trying to replace what's after $FileCreateMode, i'll try different typo, thanks

Comment: @MichaelVehrs i tried grep -H but i can't store my path in a variable with it. I'm trying something with a for loop to see how i can get it but my outputs don't differ between regular grep and grep -H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$()` to assign the results of grep into a variable, and then use a for loop to process files one by one:

```
# Assign grep results to FILES
FILES=$(grep -l '^$FileCreateMode' /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf)

# Check if FILES variable is not empty
if [[ -n ${FILES} ]]; then
    # Loop through all the files
    for file in ${FILES}; do
        # ...
        sed -iE "s/^(\\\$FileCreateMode\s+)[[:digit:]]+/\1${rep2}/" ${file}
        # ...
    done
else
    # OP's logic for when $FileCreateMode doesn't exist in any of the files
```

**`sed` fix:**

Notice that I've also updated your `sed` expression (above). You were very close, but you had to double escape the dollar sign: once for using it inside "", and once so that it isn't interpreted as END_OF_LINE in the regex.

Comment: The `-R` option is unnecessary if you enumerate all the input files on the command line.

Comment: Good spot @tripleee! I've updated `grep -Rl` to be just `grep -l`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, deleted my comment, I'm blind, sorry!

Comment: `for file in $(grep -l ...)` would work as well, though; there is no need to store the result in a variable or separately check if the result is empty.

Comment: @tripleee, using `for file in $(grep -l ...)` would omit a logical ELSE condition in the OP's question.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I agree with you about "whitespace or glob characters in the filenames". However, since the OP is grep-ing in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` the likelihood of those chars popping up is quite small. So dealing with them would only introduce an unnecessary complexity to the script.

Comment: @UmkaDK Thanks a lot that was what i was looking for ! with the loop it works as i wanted it too. And for the sed i managed to make it work with this syntax : sed -i -e "/^\$FileCreateMode/ s/ .*/ $rep2/" but i'll check your syntax because it look more complete. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `-H`, you could just do:

```
while grep -H "^\$FileCreateMode" /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf \
        | IFS=: read path line; do

        # Here, $path is the path to the file that matches
        # and $line is the line that matched.
done
```

If you prefer, you can use `if ...; then` instead of `while ...; do`  Be aware that the variables will lose their value after the subshell terminates.

Comment: Using `while grep ...; do ... done` omits a logical ELSE condition in the OP's question, and placing "$FileCreateMode doesn't exist in rsyslog conf files" code inside the loop would introduce unnecessary inefficiencies.